# How to use UnhandledExceptionEventHandler in MSTest c# dotnet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, mstest

I have a simple class as below. I'm unable to print the exceptions for the below unit test using the UnhandledExceptionEventHandler. Is there anything I'm missing. I have tested the same lines of code using console application and it prints the exception from the UnhandledException Handler. Same doesn't work for me when I use MStest. I'm using the latest version of MStest

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblyInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {            
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += currentDomain_UnhandledException;                     
    }

    static void currentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        if (ex != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("===============================");
            Console.WriteLine("===============================");
            Console.WriteLine("Test failed:" + ex);
        }            
    }
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void RaiseEvents()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is from Unhandled exception:======================");
            Exception e = (Exception)eventArgs.ExceptionObject;
            Console.WriteLine($@"{sender.ToString()}\t\t{e.Message}{e.GetBaseException()}
        {e.InnerException}{e.Data}{e.Source}{e.StackTrace}");
        };
        var list = new List<string>();
        var firstItem = list.FirstOrDefault().Contains("a");
        Console.WriteLine($"First Item is:{firstItem}");
    }

    [AssemblyCleanup]
    public static void AssemblyCleanUp()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line you expect an unhandled exception to raise? I couldn't see it in your test methods

Comment: In this line :  var firstItem = list.FirstOrDefault().Contains("a"); in RaiseEvents TestMethod

Comment: Try `First()` to be sure?

Comment: Either First() or FirstOrDefault will raise an exception on this as the list is empty. Any of the method which call on null or empty will raise an exception and my objective is to capture such unhandled exceptions using EventHandler.

Comment: I'm guessing mstest itself installs a handler that eats the exception. This has been asked here before, but not answered, as far as I know.